# Replace file text between two words across multiple lines

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

Given a text file I want to replace all the text (across multiple lines) between two given words.

Text file example:

```
line1
line2
XstartX
line4
XendX
line5
```

if I wanted to replace all the text between `start` and `end` with `YYY`
the resulting file should be

```
line1
line2
XstartYYYendX
line5
```

I tried

```
$file='C:\Path\to\file.txt'

$raw = Get-Content $file -Raw
$raw -ireplace '(?<=start).+?(?=end)', 'YYY'
$raw | Set-Content $file
```

but... no luck!

Comment: Try `$raw -ireplace '(?sm)(?<=start).+?(?=end)', 'YYY'` You'll also need to set the changed value to the var, at the moment you just output to screen.

Comment: it works! i was missing the `(?sm)` can you, please, explain and answer so that i can choose it as the right answer?

Comment: I also noticed something I was missing... line 4 of the script should be `$raw = $raw -ireplace '(?sm)(?<=start).+?(?=end)', 'YYY'`

Comment: `(?s)` should suffice. `.` normally doesn't match linefeed characters, so your expression wouldn't match text across multiple lines without the `(?s)` modifier. Alternatively you could use `[\s\S]+?` instead of `.+?` to match any character (including linefeeds).

Comment: it's true, `(?s)` is enough!  `.` is working fine even with multiple lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll need to enable the `s` modifier to have the `.+?`part also match line breaks.
As Ansgar mentions the `m` isn't neccessary here, but could enhance the `start` by anchoring at line begin with `(?<=^xstart)`

```
$file='C:\Path\to\file.txt'
$raw = Get-Content $file -Raw
$raw = $raw -ireplace '(?s)(?<=start).+?(?=end)', 'YYY'
$raw | Set-Content $file
```

Or

```
$file='C:\Path\to\file.txt'
$raw = (Get-Content $file -Raw) -ireplace '(?s)(?<=start).+?(?=end)', 'YYY'
$raw | Set-Content $file
```